# Amazon Mobile Ads Request Error

Tags: android, ads, amazon-advertising-api

I'm trying to integrate the Amazon Mobile Ads SDK into my app. I've done everything which is described in the guide - https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/mobileads/quick-start.html

1. I've added the XML amazon layout like this:

   ```
   <com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout  
   android:id="@+id/adview" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#fefefe"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
   ```
2. I've included xmlns namespace in parent layout

3.Set all permissions manifest

4.Set AdActivity in manifest

5.Set Application Key

but i get a Request_error and this message:

> We we'll be unable to create a webview for rendering an ad due to an unknown issue with webview

Can anyone please tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late to answer this, hopefully this will be useful for someone who drifts here via search...

Please declare the layout to include the ad size as well

```
<com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout
android:id="@+id/amazon_ad_layout"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
Amazon:adSize="320x50" />
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the background color attribute...

```
 <com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout  
 android:id="@+id/adview" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

if that doesn't work, take a look at [StartApp](https://portal.startapp.com//#/signup?referredBy=c9179b46-7797-5c82-3c9a-c62567ea7ce9) It's much simpler than Amazon, and works worldwide.